# Java Spark inserting CSV: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection

Hi there I'd live to insert a 10Gb CSV file in my database.
it works perfectly with small size files, but I keep having an error message with bigger ones.

Here's my code:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext
                    .read()
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                    .option("delimiter", ";")
                    .load("file:///home/1.csv");
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("mynode.mytable");
```

What is the best solution to solve this problem?
Should I split my 10Gb files into smaller ones ? Then what would be a good size ?
Should I increase the heap size?

I would choose the 1st solution but I'm not sure it's the best choice.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to repartition before savingAsTable. not doing so will result in the entire file being loaded into memory, hence the error.